# MongoDB - How to find equals in collection and in embedded document

Tags: mongodb

Gurus - I'm stuck in a situation that I can't figure out how I can query from the following collection "spouse", which has embedded document "surname" and check for equality with "surname" of this document:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("50bd2bb4fcfc6066b7ef090d"),
  "name" : "Gwendolyn",
  "surname" : "Davis",
  "birthyear" : 1978,
  "spouse" : {
    "name" : "Dennis",
    "surname" : "Evans",
    "birthyear" : 1969
  },
```

I need to query:

> Output data for all spouses with the same surnames (if the surname of
>   one of the spouses is not specified, assume that it coincides with the
>   name of another)

I tried something like this:

> db.task.find( {"surname" : { "spouse.surname" : 1 }} )

but it failed)

PLEASE PLEASE Guide me how I can achieve this any example/sample? based on this will be really helpful :-)

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have three options.

1. Use `$where` modifier:

   `db.task.find({$where: 'this.spouse.surname === this.surname'})`
2. Update all your documents and add special flag. After that you will be able to query documents by this flag. It's faster then `$where`, but requires altering your data.
3. Use [MapReduce](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/map-reduce/). It's quite complicated, but it allows you to do nearly anything.